# Error while starting Jboss server: Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, jboss

JBoss AS 6.x is getting crashed with the below error whenever I am trying to start it.

**Error:**

> 2015-12-03 16:14:18,447 ERROR [STDERR] (RMI TCP Connection(idle))
>   Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" Exception in thread
>   "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-2"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>
> 2015-12-03 16:14:31,149 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-6-thread-2) Exception in
>   thread "pool-6-thread-4" Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-3"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>
> 2015-12-03 16:14:36,308 ERROR [STDERR] (RMI TCP Connection(idle))
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>
> 2015-12-03 16:14:53,939 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-6-thread-3)
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>
> 2015-12-03 16:14:53,939 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-6-thread-4)
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>
> 2015-12-03 16:16:01,500 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] (pool-12-thread-2)
>   Unexpected error during load
>   of:org.jboss.ejb.AllowedOperationsAssociation:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>
> 2015-12-03 16:17:49,465 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-6-thread-5) Exception in
>   thread "pool-6-thread-5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>
> 2015-12-03 16:17:53,442 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-6-thread-6) Exception in
>   thread "pool-6-thread-6" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this VM argument when launching JBoss :

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

This will generate a **hprof** file when JBoss encounters an OutOfMemoryError .

This file can be analyzed with tools like ***Eclipse MAT***, and tell you which objects use the more memory.